# JavaScript regular expression returning false?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm learning javascript and this just doesn't make sense to me. `test()` returns true or false if a character is a match. So can someone please explain why my code below is not working?

```
var str = "hello*3";
var arr = str.split('');

for(var i in arr){
    re = new RegExp("/[a-z]/i");
    if(re.test(arr[i])) {
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(arr[i].charCodeAt() + 1));   
    }
}

re.test(arr[0]); //arr[0] == 'h'
// false
```

Updated example:

```
var re = new RegExp("/[a-z]/i");
re.test('h');
// returns 'false' (I'm expecting this to be true)
```

Comment: I just want it to return true if the char is [a-z]

Comment: re = new RegExp("/[a-z]/i"); should be outside your for loop btw

Comment: I still get false ...

Comment: oh no that was not the solution just an advice. @subhaze has your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `/` when using the `RegExp` and you pass flags as the second param

This should work `re = new RegExp("[a-z]", "i");`

or the literal form

`re = /[a-z]/i;`

More info can be found on MDN here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Some info from the link above

**Constructor**
Literal and constructor notations are possible:

```
/pattern/flags; 
new RegExp(pattern [, flags]);
```

**pattern**

The text of the regular expression.

**flags**

If specified, flags can have any combination of the following values:

*g*

global match

*i*

ignore case

*m*

multiline; treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working over multiple lines (i.e., match the beginning or end of each line (delimited by \n or \r), not only the very beginning or end of the whole input string)

*y*

sticky; matches only from the index indicated by the lastIndex property of this regular expression in the target string (and does not attempt to match from any later indexes). This allows the match-only-at-start capabilities of the character "^" to effectively be used at any location in a string by changing the value of the lastIndex property.

Comment: Ah I see... So basically I can do this `var re = new RegExp("[a-z]","i");` or `var re = /[a-z]/i;`

Comment: Yup! I usually just go with the literal form instead of instantiating an object

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a **[RegExp Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)** you must supply the correct syntax.

Syntax:

```
var re = new RegExp(pattern, modifiers);
var re = /pattern/modifiers;
```

So you could use either of the following here.

```
var re = new RegExp('[a-z]', 'i');
var re = /[a-z]/i;
```

Comment: Yep, thanks.. just figured that out... originally had `re = '/[a-z]/i';` which wasn't working.. which is why I opted to use `new RegExp`.. My syntax was wrong.. But since it was a Str I can see why it didn't throw a syntax error.. Well that was 10 minutes wasted. Thanks.